# Request Header issue on SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-web-access-webpart, http-400-bad-request

I've made a team site using several Excel Web Access web parts, and a little custom CSS.
However, after opening two sub sites, and going for the third, the Excel Web Access web part isn't rendering, and an error message appears: **I get the HTTP Error 400: The size of the request headers is too long.**

I found that this is a common issue, mentioned here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2012/12/27/excel-services-f5-excel-web-access-web-parts-not-rendering/

What I am interested here is that if it is related to user being in many Active Directory groups, why it started occurring for all users at a time. If this is the case it shouldn't be appearing for new user in the organization(though I have not tested it yet).What is the limit of groups by which a user can be associated with and also if any experts can provide me links/guide as how this Request header is getting created?